# Misalignment chapter titles with hang option of titlesec package and redefined \cleardoublepage

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, formatting, titlesec, blank-page

When I redefine the command \cleardoublepage to include the words "This page has been intentionally left blank", the titles of the chapters are misaligned.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=14mm, bottom=10mm, inner=15mm, outer=13mm, bindingoffset=10mm, includefoot, includehead, headsep=14mm, footskip=14mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.}{1em}{} 

\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
\vspace*{\fill}
\centering [This page is intentionally left blank]
\vspace{\fill}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\blankpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter title.}
\chapter{Misaligned chapter title illustrating the bug I'm experiencing.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's better to use something like `\raggedright` for your chapter titles (include it as part of the second mandatory argument in `\titleformat`).

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Thanks for providing an MWE in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This combines Werner's comment with a modified version of Ian Thompson's answer.

## Werner's suggestion

Werner's suggestion resolves the problem mentioned in the question but reveals a further problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=14mm, bottom=10mm, inner=15mm, outer=13mm, bindingoffset=10mm, includefoot, includehead, headsep=14mm, footskip=14mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedright}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.}{1em}{}

\newcommand{\blankpage}{%
  \vspace*{\fill}%
  \centering [This page is intentionally left blank]
  \vspace{\fill}}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{%
    \clearpage%
      \if@twoside
        \ifodd
          \c@page
        \else
          \blankpage\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
            \if@twocolumn
              \hbox{}\newpage
            \fi
        \fi
      \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter title.}
\chapter{Misaligned chapter title illustrating the bug I'm experiencing.}

Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image: A further problem]

Centring the following text is probably not what was intended here and is therefore problematic.

## Ian Thompson's answer

Ian Thompson's solution solves this problem but creates a third:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=14mm, bottom=10mm, inner=15mm, outer=13mm, bindingoffset=10mm, includefoot, includehead, headsep=14mm, footskip=14mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedright}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.}{1em}{}

\newcommand{\blankpage}{%
  \vspace*{\fill}%
  {\centering [This page is intentionally left blank]} % <--- Braces added here
  \vspace{\fill}}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{%
    \clearpage%
      \if@twoside
        \ifodd
          \c@page
        \else
          \blankpage\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
            \if@twocolumn
              \hbox{}\newpage
            \fi
        \fi
      \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter title.}
\chapter{Misaligned chapter title illustrating the bug I'm experiencing.}

Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image: Solving one problem and creating another]

This happens because `\centering` is only effective when the paragraph ends and the grouping prevents the paragraph ending so the code is never actually effective.

## Final code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=14mm, bottom=10mm, inner=15mm, outer=13mm, bindingoffset=10mm, includefoot, includehead, headsep=14mm, footskip=14mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedright}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.}{1em}{}

\newcommand{\blankpage}{%
  \vspace*{\fill}%
  {\centering [This page is intentionally left blank]\par}%
  \vspace{\fill}}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{%
    \clearpage%
      \if@twoside
        \ifodd
          \c@page
        \else
          \blankpage\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
            \if@twocolumn
              \hbox{}\newpage
            \fi
        \fi
      \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter title.}
\chapter{Misaligned chapter title illustrating the bug I'm experiencing.}

Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image: Final code]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but putting `\centering` in a group fixes the problem.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=14mm, bottom=10mm, inner=15mm, outer=13mm, bindingoffset=10mm, includefoot, includehead, headsep=14mm, footskip=14mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.}{1em}{}
\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%                                       
\vspace*{\fill}
{\centering [This page is intentionally left blank]} % <--- Braces added here
\vspace{\fill}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\blankpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
\makeatletter    
\begin{document}
\show\chapter
\chapter{First chapter title.}
\chapter{Misaligned chapter title illustrating the bug I'm experiencing.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer! And in fact all you need to fix the problem -- `\centering` is in force until the current group finishes or until another alignment is set.